# How to update nested objects if exist and not null

Tags: mapstruct

How to update nested objects only if exist and not null. I can't find solution in documentation.
My code:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
...

    @Mapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, target = "appearance", source = "appearance")
    void updateUserFromDto(UserAdminRequestDto dto, @MappingTarget User user);
}
```

Generated code:

```
@Override
    public void updateUserFromDto(UserAdminRequestDto dto, User user) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( dto.getUserId() != null ) {
            user.setUserId( dto.getUserId() );
        }
        if ( dto.getEmail() != null ) {
            user.setEmail( dto.getEmail() );
        }
    ...
      appearanceRequestDtoToAppearance1( dto.getAppearance(), user.getAppearance() );
    ...
```

Generated method appearanceRequestDtoToAppearance1

```
protected void appearanceRequestDtoToAppearance1(AppearanceRequestDto appearanceRequestDto, Appearance mappingTarget) {
        if ( appearanceRequestDto == null ) {
            return;
        }

        mappingTarget.setBodyType( appearanceRequestDto.getBodyType() );
        mappingTarget.setHairColour( appearanceRequestDto.getHairColour() );
        mappingTarget.setAge( appearanceRequestDto.getAge() );
        mappingTarget.setHeight( appearanceRequestDto.getHeight() );
       ...
       }
```

Instead of it I need something like this:

```
...
if(appearanceRequestDto.getBodyType() != null)
mappingTarget.setBodyType( appearanceRequestDto.getBodyType() );
if(appearanceRequestDto.getHairColour() != null)
mappingTarget.setHairColour( appearanceRequestDto.getHairColour() );
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to define your own method for updating the `AppearanceRequestDto` and control how you want it to happen. Or define it on the global level on the `@Mapper`.

e.g. Custom appearance update mapping

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
...

    void updateUserFromDto(UserAdminRequestDto dto, @MappingTarget User user);


    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
    void updateAppearanceFromDto(@MappingTarget Appearance mappingTarget, AppearanceRequestDto appearanceRequestDto) 
}
```